# How can await promise resolve if resolve(...) is inside setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, stack, queue

What is the order of execution for code below?

If await makes us wait for "promise" to resolve, but resolve(...) is inside a setTimeout, and a setTimeout only gets executed after the stack is empty... How are we not frozen on await? Are there not still things on the stack when we are "await"ing? Is there some exception to an await-y setTimeout , or am I not understanding the stack?

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}


f();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` is basically a substitute for `.then` - it says "do the rest of this stuff only once the Promise has resolved". It does not freeze the interpreter at the point of the `await` - it only pauses execution flow *for the current function* until the Promise resolves.

So

```
// wait until the promise resolves (*)
```

might be more accurately read as

```
// pause execution of this function until the promise resolves (*)
```

> Are there not still things on the stack when we are "await"ing?

Yes, `f()` returns a Promise (from the async function) synchronously while the `await promise` is being waited on to resolve. Then the script doesn't do anything else, so the call stack lies completely empty until the `setTimeout` macrotask runs a second later, adding a short task that calls `resolve`, which queues a microtask that shortly results in `done` being logged.

There are a number of times during your code in which there is no currently active task.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply - it helped. So... if there were more code after the last line in my code (something below 'f();') - would that have to be executed before the await promise gets resolved? And if so, would that be due to both 'let result = await ...' being like a .then handler, AND the setTimeout? And if you have a minute could you also tell me which are these "number of times during your code in which there is no currently active task". Sorry for all the questions - you've already been very helpful.

Comment: Exactly. Once the `await` is reached inside the function, the function pauses and (1) waits for all other synchronous code below it to complete (2) waits for the timeout to spawn a new macrotask (3) when the macrotask runs, `resolve` is called, adding a new task to the queue, which runs shortly after all other synchronous code runs

Comment: The pauses are between (1) and (2) (eg 0.5 seconds later, while waiting for the timeout) and also between (2) and (3) (after `resolve` is called, when there is nothing on the call stack. Then, later, a separate task (the Promise's microtask) runs and execution resumes, resulting in `alert(result);` being run.